# Dialog doesn't fill the screen

Tags: java, android, dialog, fullscreen

I have a problem with Dialogs.

I have a simple Dialog - with only an EditText and the keyboard.
But I want the Dialog to be full screen with a small transparent background.

But if I open the Dialog, it's not full screen.

[image: My screen]

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/moja"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cele">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:hint="Enter category title"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:lines="1"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:elegantTextHeight="false"
                android:foregroundGravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
                android:background="@color/bpTransparent"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

I open the Dialog with:

```
EditItemDialog cdd=new EditItemDialog(AddItemInPacage.this,nazovtripu,position+1,indexpacage);
                cdd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                cdd.show();
```

on finally My Mainfest from thise dialog

```
 <activity
        android:name=".EditItemDialog"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" />
```

________________________________*EDIT*__________________________________________

I tried this code

```
getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

And it's nearly folling, but I need all in one color.
So the ProgressBar needs to have the same color as the background.

[image: My screen with "second" problem]

Comment: try to use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`..... in all frame layout ...

Comment: @sushildlh It won't make any difference at all. Only that `match_parent` isn't deprecated (yet).

Comment: what is deprecated means here  ? and why it is not help ? will you please explain?

Comment: yes, isn't change.    Is not fill_parrent and match_parrent is the same?

Comment: They actually **are** the same thing. Only that `fill_parent` has been deprecated for a longer name.